# Windows C++ | When writing to file, what is responsible for converting \n to \r\n?

Tags: c++, file

When writing to file, strings with `\n` get automatically converted to `\r\n`.

What is responsible for this behaviour? Is this a part of the cpp function, or something closer to the system?

Comment: This happens if you open the file without `std::ios::binary` on Windows. [Binary and text modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io#Binary_and_text_modes)

Comment: How are your writing the file? Show your code. If you are using `ostream` derived classes use `ios::binary` option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Please write it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your compiler.

When you are working with OS-specific outputs (like files or standard output), compiler is obliged to convert end-of-line escape sequence (`\n`) to OS-specific line ending - on Unix it would be a line feed (ASCII `0x0A`), on older Macs it's a carriage return (ASCII `0x0D`) and on Windows it's both.

You can avoid that by opening file in binary mode:

```
std::fstream("myFile.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the compiler is reponsible? I always guessed this is a feature of the low-level (if not even OS functions) which are responsible for this. [MSDN: Text and Binary Mode File I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/text-and-binary-mode-file-i-o?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Scheff Hmm. I always thought that C++ standard requires such behaviour, but I cannot find it, so I was probably wrong. I wonder how standard defines "binary mode" and "text mode" in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the meaning of `binary mode` and  `text mode` is implementation defined, so actually compiler isn't obliged to anything. It is also not something compiler would do anyway but the provided implementation of the stdandard library. Usually the implementation would map it to `fopen`-functionality from the C-runtime, which would map it to the functionality provided from the OS. However, also on Windows one could use a standard library which would not translate `\n` to `\r\n`  and this would be fine for the standard.